# Recorder won't start

Tags: java, android

I've been having an issue (for a week now) in which I get an error and my app crashes. The message displayed in the Logcat highlights `recorder.start` in blue. If I try to catch the thrown exception then the error points to `recorder.stop`. Please help.

```
 private MediaRecorder recorder;
private MediaPlayer myPlayer;
private String OUTPUTFILE;
private TextView myCount;
private Button Play;
private Button Next;
private TextView myQuestion;
private int value;


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // do something
                try {
                    setupMediaRecorder();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                fiveSeconds();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording);



    OUTPUTFILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/audiorecorder.3gp";
    myCount  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myCount);
    Play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Play);
    Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
    myQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myQuestion);


    //recorder.start();





    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please grand permission to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
        }
    }

    else {

        value = MainActivity.GenerateValue();
        myQuestion.setText(MainActivity.mylist.get(value) + " ./?");
        Play.setEnabled(false);
        Next.setEnabled(false);

        try {
            setupMediaRecorder();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fiveSeconds();

        Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Play.setTag("Play");

                if(Play.getTag() == "Play"){
                    playBack();
                    Play.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause));
                    Play.setTag("Pause");
                }

                else if (Play.getTag() == "Pause") {
                    stopPlayBack();
                    Play.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
                    Play.setTag("Play");
                }

            }
        });

        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Make_Notes.class);
                startActivity(theIntent);
            }
        });





    }


}

private void fiveSeconds() {

    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long milliseconds) {

            //  Log.i("Seconds Left", String.valueOf(milliseconds/1000));
            myCount.setText(String.valueOf(milliseconds / 1000));
            if (milliseconds / 1000 < 4) {
                myCount.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            recorder.start();


            sixtySeconds();










            Toast.makeText(Recording.this, "Start!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }.start();
}

private void sixtySeconds() {
    CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long milliseconds) {

            // Log.i("Seconds Left", String.valueOf(milliseconds/1000));
            myCount.setText(String.valueOf(milliseconds / 1000));
            if (milliseconds / 1000 < 4) {
                myCount.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }

        public void onFinish() {


                recorder.stop();





            Play.setEnabled(true);
            Next.setEnabled(true);

        }
    }.start();


}

private void stopRecording(){
    if(recorder != null){
        recorder.stop();

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There is no recorder to play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private void playBack(){

    myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        myPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUTFILE);
        myPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myPlayer.start();


}

private void stopPlayBack(){
    myPlayer.stop();

    Toast.makeText(this, "There is no media to stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



}

private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    //recorder.reset();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUTFILE);
    recorder.prepare();




}
```

}

This is the `manifest.xml` which shows that I've already given access to `Record_Audio` and `External_Storage`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The Logcat error:

```
Process: com.example.abdullah.be_fluent, PID: 7054
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:1309)
    at com.example.abdullah.be_fluent.Recording$3.onFinish(Recording.java:159)
    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: How does it point to `recorder.stop` if you catch the error?

Comment: One error in your code is in `OUTPUTFILE = Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/audiorecorder.3gp";` where you use the storage state as base directory instead of the storage directory.

Comment: Well if I caught only the start not the stop then it will show an error, regards the OUTPUTFILE how do I fix it ?

Comment: changing     Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/audiorecorder.3gp" to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audiorecorder.3gp" didn't work any other suggestions ?

Comment: Read the API documentation which type of object is returned by getExternalStorageDirectory. Then read for this type how to retrieve a String object with the path from it.

Comment: Sorry, I did't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: Sorry, I did't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: Which data type (class) is returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` according to Java API documentation?

Comment: I am sorry again, I am new to this. Where can I find the API documentation ?

Comment: If you don't know this you should start with [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), then the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/docs/) containing tutorials and the [Android API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages)

Comment: I did take a course in android studio which contained the essentials of Java but neither to say I tried to add getAbsolutePath() after .getExternalStorageDirectory(), and that didn't work either but the Logcat error doesn't point me to the outputfile at all it pointing me to the recorder.start().

Comment: The `getExternalStorageState()` isn't the only error in the code. Another possible problem I see now is that you call `fiveSeconds()` (to start recording) the first time before calling `setupMediaRecorder()` to prepare recording.

Comment: Yes you were right I had the fiveseconds before setupMediaRecorder, I fixed it but still having the same issue :( btw I updated the code and the Logcat error.

Comment: Next possible problem is that you request permission to record audio but not to write external storage. But I will stop here because in my opinion you need more experience with smaller apps and Android in general before trying to make this work.

Comment: Well I see your point regards the external storage it makes sense, in any case thanks man for everything :)